# Word VBA: how to select found text rather than where the cursor is positioned

Tags: vba, find, ms-word

This is probably simple but I can't get it to work.

I need to search through my document, find words that contain the string 'alog' and add 'ue'. For example, 'catalogs' --> 'catalogues'.

The above works fine but I can't get the next bit to work: if a found string already has 'ue' after the 'log' I don't want to add another 'ue'.

The subroutine accessed from the macro is below. I've tried adding the following lines into the 'while execute' part, but 'selection' always turns out to be the word where the cursor happens to be.

```
With Selection

    .Expand unit:=wdWord

End With
```

How do I i) select the content of the found range and ii) expand that new selection by two characters to see if those two characters are 'ue' ?

Many thanks.

```
    Sub do_replace2(old_text As String, new_text As String, Count_changes As Integer)

    ' Replaces 'log' with 'logue'
    ' Ignores paragraphs in styles beginning with 'Question'

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ActiveDocument.Range

    With rg.Find
    .Text = old_text
    While .Execute
        If Left(rg.Paragraphs(1).Style, 8) <> "Question" Then
            rg.Text = new_text
                With ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(rg, "Changed from '" & old_text & "'")
                .Initial = "-logs"
                .Author = "-logs"
                End With
                Count_changes = Count_changes + 1
           End If
     rg.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I follow the first part of your question "How do I select the content of the found range".  The `rg` variable already contains the search result. If you want to select it, just use `rg.Select`. This might be useful in debugging (so you can see where the `Range` is when you're stepping through the code), but there isn't really any other reason to *use* the `Selection` object in the code from your question.  You can just use the `Range` object instead.

As to part 2 of your question "How do I ... expand that new selection by two characters", all you need to do is add 2 to the `.End` property of the `Range`.  Since you're only using this for a test (and because the `.Find` method can be dodgy), test this on a *copy* of `rg`:

```
With rg.Find
    .Text = old_text
    While .Execute
        If Left(rg.Paragraphs(1).Style, 8) <> "Question" Then
            Dim test As Range
            Set test = rg.Duplicate         'copy the found Range.
            test.Collapse wdCollapseEnd     'move to the end of it.
            test.End = test.End + 2         'expand to the next 2 characters.
            If test.Text <> "ue" Then       'see if it's "ue".
                rg.Text = new_text
                With ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(rg, "Changed from '" & old_text & "'")
                    .Initial = "-logs"
                    .Author = "-logs"
                End With
                Count_changes = Count_changes + 1
            End If
        End If
        rg.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
End With
```

Comment: Thanks comintern; as I said the end + 2 works fine, gives me a range start of (say) 735 and an end of 737 with a string therein. But if I do .wdcollapsestart, and .start + 5, the range start and end are the same and the string is null. Why doesn't 'start' work the same way as 'end'?

Comment: Another update: when I do this:
    test.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    test.Start = test.Start - 5

it works fine. Can't you do 'start + n'?